# Django: Template Language comparison always returns false

Tags: python, django

In a project I'm working on, I need the `select` tag to be on a specific `option` by default. I'm trying to make it do that if I set a variable to a certain number, the corresponding option will be selected when the page loads. For some reason, the code I'm using to tell if the option is the same as the variable always returns false.

View.py

```
@login_required
def display_work(request, id, chapter = 1):
    info = dict()
    work = Work.objects.get(id = id)
    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(work = id).order_by("order_number")
    info['title'] = work.title
    info['summery'] = work.summery
    info['current_chapter'] = chapter # the number the options are compared to
    print chapter
    info['id'] = id
    num_chapters = 0
    chapter_list = []
    for c in chapters:
        temp = (c.title, c.order_number) # where the numbering for the options is set (see template code)
        chapter_list.append(temp)
        num_chapters += 1
    info['total_chapter'] = num_chapters
    content = chapters[int(chapter)-1].content
    return render_to_response("SubMain/display_work.html", {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, "info":info, "chapters": chapter_list, "content": content})
```

Template: The template runs through a list, checking to see if the option its creating is the current chapter. If so, it should "select" it.

```
{% for t, o in chapters %}
<option value="/work/{{ info.id }}/{{ o }}" {% if o == info.current_chapter %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Chapter {{ o }}: {{ t }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Yet whenever I run the code, nothing gets selected (has what's in the if tag). Through the debugging I've done, I've confirmed that `o` is 2 and `info.current_chapter` is 2 as well.

Comment: Are you certain that both `o` and `info.current_chapter` are the same type? Both should be `int()`, but perhaps one of them is a string (usually because it came from a request variable).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought of that, but I think that they're both the same type. The `info.curent_chapter` isn't a request variable (Wait, do URL parameters count?) and `o` comes from the integer field of a model.

Comment: Yes, URL parameters do count. Doublecheck your types (use `repr()` to verify, `print 1` and `print '1'` look the same on the console).

Answer (score 1):

In the template try using single '=' operation instead of '=='.

```
<option value="/work/{{ info.id }}/{{ o }}" {% if o = info.current_chapter %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Chapter {{ o }}: {{ t }}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ifequal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal)

```
 {% for t, o in chapters %}
    <option value="/work/{{ info.id }}/{{ o }}" {% ifequal o info.current_chapter %} selected="selected" {% endifequal %}>Chapter {{ o }}: {{ t }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```